# Kotlin - accessing and using constructor parameters

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dictionary, constructor

I have this constructor in a class inside my interface (it's supposed to be more like a static structure but for now this is ok)

```
class BinData {
        constructor(card_id: Int,
                    from: Int,
                    to: Int)
    }
```

I created an instance, and I want to use all properties inside constructor in a form of a map as an argument for function

```
val binData = IConfiguration.BinData(2, 222100, 272099)
memoryConfig.binAdd(1, binData)
```

Of course then, when I printed the line in binAdd() I got
Bin added: {1=control.app.activities.IConfiguration$BinData@8bd0008} which is just object hash

What is the reasonable way to approach this?
I thought of a creating a method like BinData.getdata() which would return Map of parameters but I'm really not sure that's the way.

For any help I'll be glad. Thanks.

Comment: Why is this not a data class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructor parameters can only be properties if they are in the primary constructor, declared before the `{ }`. And `toString()` will only list the property values if your class is a data class or if you override `toString()` to manually define this behavior.

You should declare your class like this:

```
data class BinData(
    val card_id: Int,
    val from: Int,
    val to: Int
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're just declaring a constructor that receives 3 parameters but you're not specifying that those are properties. I'd recommend you setting a primary constructor with those properties

```
class BinData(val card_id: Int,
              val from: Int,
              val to: Int)
```

Notice that I specified those properties as `val` assuming that they're immutable. If you need to modify them, make them mutable by defining them as `var`

Consider also using a [data class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html) if your class is meant to only hold values and not logic

Comment: Data classes can certainly hold logic.  They are just _prinarily_ holders of their fields.

Comment: Of course they can, but their main purpose is to hold data. That seems to be the case here. Even though they can hold logic, I'd not think of modeling a use case or repository as data classes

Comment: Thanks! This did it for me. I knew data classes only from python, but it was exactly what i needed for this type of stuff